# How can I sort the post by the score? - React typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sorting

Im creating **4 posts** which have their own score and details from chakraUi. The score is calculated from how many like, comment, and share that post have.

```
export type PostProps = {
    id: string
    name: string
    dateTime: string
    message: string
    likes: number
    comments: number
    shares: number
    avatar: string
    media: string
    score?: number
}

    return (
        <Box p="3" minW="sm" maxW="sm" borderWidth="1px" borderRadius="lg" overflow="hidden" fontWeight="semibold">
            <Text align="right"> score: {props.score} </Text>
            <HStack>
                <Avatar size="md" name={props.name} src={props.avatar} />
                <VStack spacing="0.5" align={"-moz-initial"}>
                    <Text align="left">{props.name}</Text>
                    <Text align="left" color="gray.500" fontWeight="semibold" fontSize="xs">
                        {props.dateTime}
                    </Text>
                </VStack>
            </HStack>
            <Container p="1" fontWeight="normal">
                {props.message}
                <Image src={props.media} alt="" p="1" fit={"cover"} />
            </Container>
            <HStack spacing="0.5">
                <Icon as={AiFillLike} color="#E65300"></Icon>
                <Text p="1" fontSize="xs">
                    {props.likes} {props.comments} {props.shares}
                </Text>
                <Icon as={AiOutlineShareAlt}></Icon>
            </HStack>
        </Box>


    )

}
```

```
 return (
    <VStack>
        <AlgoTester></AlgoTester>
        <Post
            id="1"
            name="Mr.Cat 1"
            dateTime={CurrentDate()} /*"23m"*/
            message="Hello from the other side!"
            // likes=RandomNumber()
            likes={RandomNumber()}
            comments={RandomNumber()}
            shares={RandomNumber()}
            avatar="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/48/RedCat_8727.jpg"
            media="https://img.freepik.com/premium-vector/boy-waving-hand-greeting-cute-people-illustration_107355-500.jpg?w=1380"
            score={200}
        />
        <Post
            id="2"
            name="Mr.Cat 2"
            dateTime={CurrentDate()} /*"1d"*/
            message="Seek success, but always be prepared for random cats."
            // likes={Math.floor(Math.random() * 1001)}
            likes={RandomNumber()}
            comments={RandomNumber()}
            shares={RandomNumber()}
            avatar="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/48/RedCat_8727.jpg"
            media="https://img.freepik.com/premium-vector/smiling-young-man-showing-thumbs-up-illustration-hand-drawn-style_213307-233.jpg?w=1380"
            score={100}
        />
        <Post
            id="3"
            name="Mr.Cat 3"
            dateTime={CurrentDate()} /*"4h"*/
            message="Sometimes I stare at a door or a wall and I wonder what is this reality, why am I alive, and what is this all about?"
            // likes={Math.floor(Math.random() * 1001)}
            likes={RandomNumber()}
            comments={RandomNumber()}
            shares={RandomNumber()}
            avatar="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/48/RedCat_8727.jpg"
            media="https://img.freepik.com/premium-vector/big-obstacle-concept-illustration_1133-825.jpg?w=1800"
            score={800}
        />
        <Post
            id="4"
            name="Mr.Cat 4"
            dateTime={CurrentDate()} /*"14m"*/
            message="Football is a family of team sports that involve, to varying degrees, kicking a ball to score a goal. Unqualified, the word football normally means the form of football that is the most popular where the word is used. Sports commonly called football include association football (known as soccer in North America and Oceania);
            gridiron football (specifically American football or Canadian football); Australian rules football; rugby union and rugby league; and Gaelic football. These various forms of football share to varying extent common origins and are known as football codes."
            // likes={Math.floor(Math.random() * 1001)}
            likes={RandomNumber()}
            comments={RandomNumber()}
            shares={RandomNumber()}
            avatar="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/48/RedCat_8727.jpg"
            media=""
            score={250}
        />
    </VStack>
)
```

How to sort those post by Descending sort(desc)

Comment: It looks like the code you posted is for 1 individual post. If you want help on sorting how you sho many posts, can you please share the code where you render multiple posts?

Comment: @BlunderingPhilosopher Yeah I added the 4 posts in order by putting the number of scores directly.

Comment: Cool thanks for adding that - it looks like you are currently hard-coding all of your data for each post. What I mean is, you're passing props directly to each Post. Normally in a website you would get data from an API request, that data will be in the form of an array, then you use `.map` to loop through the array and dynamically display this to the end user. It will be easier for you to do this, as you will also be able to take advantage of the array `.sort` function before displaying each Post. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

you can use .sort function of array in js like this. let's assume PostPropsArray is an array that has all the posts.

```
PostPropsArray.sort((a, b) =>
      a.score < b.score ? -1 : 1
    );
```